# How to convert a binary to a char or String ?, Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, char, byte

I know this may be a simple question but really i just can't solve this thing!
what i want is to convert an array into a char
i mean, let's suppose that someArray has into it {1,0,1,0,1,0}, and in binary, 10101010 = ª
now, how can i do that? is there something like arrayToChar(byte) or something like that? 
my idea is to make a class with all the conversions like

```
if(someArray.equals(10101010)){
return "ª";
}
```

but i know there must be an easier an shorter way to do this, any ideas?
 :( please help

Comment: What is the type of `someArray`?

Comment: someArray is integer, it's supposed to be byte[] but i just dont' know how to work with that kind of type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct binary for `a` is `1100001`. And you could do it (in Java 8+) with something like

```
int[] arr = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IntStream.of(arr).forEach(x -> sb.append(x));
char ch = (char) Integer.parseInt(sb.toString(), 2);
System.out.println(ch);
```

**or** without converting to a `String` (and in earlier versions of Java) like

```
int v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    v += arr[arr.length - i - 1] * Math.pow(2, i);
}
System.out.println((char) v);
```

Both output (as requested)

```
a
```

Comment: thanks a lot! :) how would be the reverse algorithm like? (a -> 1100001) 
do i have to change the 4 line?

Comment: @tasipa `Integer.toBinaryString(int)` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int[] myArray = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0};
    int i = IntStream.of(myArray).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a * 2 + b);
    String s = Character.toString((char)i);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray) + " -> " + s);
    // [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] -> *
```